# html Modify the value of the name so that it can be used more than once

Tags: javascript, html

I have a value in the html page

```
<div id="example"></div>
```

.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
            <div id="example"></div>
                <div id="example"></div>
                
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

and the app.js . page

```
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML="ax-max";
```

.

When I put `<div id = "example"> </div>` in the html page more than once, it only works once.
I want someone to help me make it multiple so I can put it everywhere on the page

Comment: Use a class and `document.getelementsbyclassname`

Comment: ID, by definition, are supposed to be unique; if you want to have a "group" name, instead, you can use the `class` attribute or a custom attribute (e.g. `data-groupid`); then you can select them with `document.querySelectorAll()`. By the way, you cannot place DIVs inside the HEAD section, they have to be in the BODY

Answer (score 1):

this is normal, an id can only be used once in an HTML page. The method I advise you is to use a class, which has the same role as an id but can be used several times in the same page

Here is an example:

```
<div class="example"></div>
<div class="example"></div>
```

```
document.getElementsByClassName("example");
```

More info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use classes instead of ids. Select all elements. Use forEach to set the inner html.

```
<div class="example"></div>
<div class="example"></div>
<div class="example"></div>
<div class="example"></div>
```

```
const els = document.querySelectorAll('.example')

els.forEach(el => {
  el.innerHTML = 'test'
})
```

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't use id multiple times. Try className instead.

Please read it [MDN id attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)